# Как заменить символ в файле, найденный в регулярном выражении python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, замена

Пытаюсь заменить символ через регулярное выражение, но выдает ошибку, так как `re.search` является объектом соответствия, а не строкой. Есть регулярка, которая находит фразу до нижнего подчеркивания. Не могу разобраться, как можно через регулярное выражение поменять последний символ, `_` к примеру на `-`.

```
import os
import re
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/test/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
             with open(filepath, 'r+', encoding='windows-1251') as f:
                 text = f.read()
                 result=re.search(r"(Началофразы)\s*(.*?)\s*(?!\1)(?:[_])",text)            
                 print(result)


             with open(filepath, 'w', encoding='windows-1251') as f:
```

Дальше возникают сложности, так как непонятно, как изменить сам символ в регулярке и сохранить новую фразу обратно в файл.
Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Текущее регулярное выражение выводит из файла из строки

```
 *<Test test="1231_1234" Началофразы="12345_12345"/>*

Начало фразы="12345_
```

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение выглядит странно. Вам нужна `re.sub` и обратные ссылки, `result=re.sub(r"((Началофразы)\s*(.*?)\s*)(?!\2)_", r"\1-",text)`

Comment: Обязательно делать при помощи регулярки?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Странно? Текущее регулярное выражение вроде работает, выводит фрагмент текста от начала нужной фразы до "_": "Начало фразы..... _ " , не совсем понимаю, что делает ваш пример, выводит все содержимое файла(

Comment: @СтаниславЕнягин Там два ключевых слова, между ними текст разный каждый раз, боюсь, что без регулярки никак..

Comment: можете привести пример строки к которой применяется `re.search`?

Comment: Вам необходимо записать в файл текст между этими двумя ключевыми словами?

Comment: @Violet Фрагмент из файла <Test test="1231_1234" Началофразы="12345_12345"/>
Регулярка применяется ко всему файлу и находит нужный фрагмент Началофразы="12345_

Comment: @СтаниславЕнягин Да, заменить символ _ на - (последний, если так проще).

Comment: Но _ в файле много, поэтому не могу воспользоваться обыкновенной заменой всех символов(

Comment: `print(''.join(re.findall(r'Началофразы.*[_]', '<Test test="1231_1234" Началофразы="12345_12345"/>')).replace('"', '').replace('_', '-'))` ?

Comment: @Violet Спасибо огромное! То, что нужно, создал две переменные на основе вашего кода (буду разбираться как это работает) и теперь новая фраза записывается в файл))

Comment: можно ещё попробовать использовать `\s[а-яА-Я]*\W*\d*[_]`, только не забудьте `replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

a = '<Test test="1231_1234" Началофразы="12345_12345"/>'
print(''.join(re.findall(r'\s[а-яА-Я]*\W*\d*[_]', a)).replace('"', '').replace(' ', '').replace('_', '-'))
```

- `join` - отвечает за объединение списка строк с помощью определенного указателя
- `re.findall` - возвращает список всех найденных совпадений
- `\s` - пробел
- `[а-яА-Я]*` - любые символы от a до я или от A до Я несколько подряд
- `\W*` - что-нибудь, кроме буквы, цифры или символа подчеркивания несколько подряд
- `\d*` - любая десятичная цифра несколько подряд
- `[_]` - Соответствует символу `_`
- `replace` - возвращает копию строки, в которой заменены все вхождения указанной строки указанным значением

https://regex101.com/r/xJY6np/1